# Web Application Server migrate from 7.0 to 8.5.5.4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ibm-was

We migrate from WAS 7.0 to WAS 8.5.5.4 with JRE 7.0 in my compagny, as all dependency are not open source, i haven't information on the goal of the following :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>ibm</groupId>
<artifactId>com.ibm.ws.runtime</artifactId>
<version>${com.ibm.ws.runtime.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>ibm</groupId>
<artifactId>etools.xsd.bean.runtime</artifactId>
<version>${etools.xsd.bean.runtime.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>ibm</groupId>
<artifactId>j2ee</artifactId>
<version>${j2ee.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>ibm</groupId>
<artifactId>marshall</artifactId>
<version>${ibm.marshall.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>ibm</groupId>
<artifactId>wsatlib</artifactId>
<version>${ibm.wsatlib.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

My question is, did i need to update the following dependency ( by default i think yes, because there are linked to the 7.0 was) ? In this case, what's the dependency in WAS 8555, i know that IBM has change the groupId/ArtifactId of the dependency in WAS 85554. As i don't know the utility of the denpendancy actually i'am not able to do the link with news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you would use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
    <artifactId>was</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/localrepo.htm?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5&lang=en for POM dependencies.

Cindy

Comment: thanks a lot, in fact my compagny have add before the dependency of WAS with the good name on the repository of Nexus.